# MapInfo and large GIS data

Tags: raster, mapinfo, performance

I have a very large map file (.TIF) and a large DTM file (.GRD).
When I add them to my layers in MapInfo I get a .TAB file.

When my Map / DTM are visible MapInfo works and responds really slow and sometimes crashes.

I wanted to know, what can be done so that I could work with large layers with better performance and in one piece?

I have Global Mapper if some kind of conversion is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your map (image) and grid/DTM are in the same projection/coordinate system; and that your Map > Options > Image processing reprojection is set to 'Never'. And I agree that .ecw is best for image performance.

Comment: Hi, The processing reprojection did the trick. Now everything works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Large TIFF files used to be a killer for speed and good performance. Personally I haven't used those for ages since there are better formats out there for large raster files such as ECW.

Large grid files can have some of the same drawbacks as TIFF files as they mostly aren't using pyramiding or other technics to boost the performance.

You don't specify the sizes of your datasets, but Pitney Bowes is working on a new 64-bit product for working with grid and raster. It will be called MapInfo Pro Advanced and it's an add-on for MapInfo Pro similar to Discover and Vertical Mapper.

We do currently have a trial version that you can try out if you want to. Have a look at this article from The MapInfo Pro Monthly Journal: [Get on the Grid: A look at the powerful grid coloring capabilities in MapInfo Pro Raster](http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-aug-2015/MI-Pro-Raster-Get-On-The-Grid).

In the article you will also find information about how to get a copy of a the trial version.

With MapInfo Pro Advanced we are also introducing a new grid and raster format: MRR, Multi-Resolution Raster. You can read more about this new raster format in this article: [Get on the Grid with MapInfo Pro Raster](http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-jul-2015/MapInfo-Pro-Raster-Overview)

With this new technology you will not have problems working with large grids; that's grid at +100 GB.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I use the MapInfo core as a part of another software (Radio Planing) so I don't think the new version is for me.. 

I also tried a .ECW of the same file (8Gb) and still got a poor performance.

Can I create Pyramids / Tiles for it for better performance?

Comment: ECW should create the pyramiding for you. I know we (Pitney Bowes) have partners working on porting Radio Planning software to the new 64-bit engine of MapInfo Pro Advanced. I'm not sure exactly what product and what the time frame is however. Can you check if you have poor performance if you only use one of the two datasets you mention above. Maybe the poor performance is related to just one of them

Comment: Hi, The map is mainly the problem. would it help if I split the map into tiles and then create a seamless Layer from it? I am open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It might. Normally I would however say that you would get a good performance from an ECW